# Is there a way to dynamically change conditions in if statement in Java?

Tags: java, conditional-statements

I have this code that filters a String `str`, keeping only some `chars`, resulting in the reduced String `fStr`. The subtlety is that I only keep a target `char`, if it is not equal to the last `char` in `fStr`:

```
ArrayList<Character> targetChars = //{a, b, c};
String str = "axxbxxxxbxbxcxa", fStr = "";

for(int i = 0, s = 0 ; i < str.length() ; i++) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);
    if(targetChars.contains(c)) {
        if(s > 0 && fStr.charAt(s-1) != c) {
            fStr += c;
            s++;
        }
    }
}
```

> fStr → "abca"

In the innermost `if` statement, I have to include `s > 0` before `fStr.charAt(s-1) != c`, otherwise the latter will throw an `OutOfBounds` exception the first time `targetChars.contains(c)` is `true`. But *only* the first time, it annoys me that the loop will always check that I won't be out of bounds, given that it only has to do it once. I know I could do something like that:

```
ArrayList<Character> targetChars = //{a, b, c};
String str = "auebskrubnbocpa", fStr = "";
int i = 0, s = 0;   

for(; i < str.length() ; i++) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);
    if(targetChars.contains(c)) {
            fStr += c;
            s++;
            i++;
            break;
    }
}

for(; i < str.length() ; i++) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);
    if(targetChars.contains(c)) {
        if(fStr.charAt(s-1) != c) {
            fStr += c;
            s++;
        }
    }
}
```

But is there a more elegant and less annoying way to dynamically truncate a conditional statement?

Comment: after you record each char, why don't you store that in some variable and keep referring to it?

Comment: @Constantin I understand what you mean, that would work here. But this is just an example, I was wondering if, in general, there is some mechanism to deal with situation like that, where the initial condition is more complicated

Comment: if you dont want to use s, you might try something like if(fStr.charAt(fStr.length() - 1) != c) ... but you will have to take care for empty fStr

Comment: @Constantin you would still have to check `fStr.length() != 0`

Comment: yes that's correct ... are you just lkooking for an elegant solution?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to dynamically change conditions in if statement in Java?

No there isn't.  The original version of your code is the best from a readability perspective.

However, if you are concerned about efficiency, then you should be using a `StringBuilder` rather than `fStr += c`.

Also a `char[]` and an explicit `for` loop is likely to be faster than `ArrayList<Character>.contains`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it, but not sure if it suits your needs

```
public class Example {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] targetChars = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
    String str = "axxbxxxxbxbxcxa", fStr = " ";

    for(int i = 0 ; i < str.length() ; i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if(isAcceptableChar(c, targetChars)) {

            if(fStr.charAt(fStr.length() - 1) != c) {
                fStr = fStr.trim() + c;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(fStr);       
}


private static boolean isAcceptableChar(char newChar, char[] targetChars) {
    boolean value = false;

    for(char ch : targetChars){
        if(ch == newChar) {
            value = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return value;
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is, just call a function that returns a boolean value that you use in your if condition. Different functions could be called at different times by using a function pointer.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, because you are saying to just bury the condition in a method, that doesn't address the issue, the method would have to do same thing internally...

Comment: I see you missed the part about using a function pointer and changing the function that the pointer points at, in response to certain conditions. This is a standard idiom.

Comment: then could you please expand, I don't know what a function pointer is in Java? Could you show an example?

Comment: Java does not know the concept of function pointers. I think your are talking about C.

Comment: The concept of function pointers is simulated in Java using Interface class.

Comment: I have an example, but it will not post. I get an error saying it is too long. Here is the gist: ' public interface Condition {
    boolean eval( String s, int index, char c );
  }

  public static final Condition c1 = new Condition() {
    public boolean eval( String s, int index, char c ) {
      return index > 0 && s.charAt(index-1) != c;
    }
  };

  public static final Condition c2 = new Condition() {
    public boolean eval( String s, int index, char c ) {
      return s.charAt(index-1) != c;
    }
  };
`